# Audio stops after a while or music change in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm facing an issue which i fix every time by unplugging and plugging the jack in audio output in my motherboard,
i tried removing all sound drivers such as alsa and pulseaudio, then reinstall them, but nothing changed, audio stops each time i change the music.

OS : Arch Linux x64
Motherboard : MSI MS-7817

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my MSI laptop. Upgrading to the latest kernel from LTS solved it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/433168)